# porque me cambia el valor de la variable a root. PHP

Tags: php

Como se puede ver la variable $userName tiene valor manuel y debajo valor root y no funciona la consulta.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx. No, no se puede ver. Por favor, ve a [edit] y haz que el código vaya como texto, al igual que los errores. Las capturas de pantalla limítalas a las salidas/detalles propios de la interfaz que intentas ajustar

Comment: Cuando accedes a la clave en el <h1>, te falta poner usuarioName entre comillas ("): $_SESSION['usuarioName'];